# Issue while uploading file from local to Snowflake table stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake and facing issue while uploading files from local to Snowflake table stage. I'm following Snowflake in 20 minutes training and stuck at the file uploading part, any help/pointer will be much appreciated. I have added the screen shot of the error in this post and below is one of the error message.

### Error Message:

| source          | target             | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status | message

```
                                   |
```

### |-----------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------------------

---------------------------------------|
| employees01.csv | employees01.csv.gz |         370 |           0 | NONE               | GZIP               | ERROR  | Unknown Error in uploading a file: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj5iva8r7\employees01.csv_c.gz#y89s9rn7, file=c:\Temp\employees01.csv, real file=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local
\Temp\tmpj5iva8r7\employees01.csv_c.gz |

Many Thanks!
Bharat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzyn7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give it try to `put file://c:\Temp\employees*.csv @%emp_basic;`

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-stage.html